# Infinite sum of Laguerre polynomials: is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(k+n)!}x^kL_n^k(x)^2=e^x+P(x)$, with $P$ a polynomial of degree $2n-1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, orthogonal-polynomials

I have the following expression:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(k+n)!}x^k(L_n^k(x))^2,
$$
where
$$
L_n^k(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j\binom{n+k}{n-j}\frac{x^j}{j!}
$$
is the usual associated Laguerre polynomial and $k\in\mathbb N$. In particular $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}x^k(L^k_n(x))^2=\frac{(k+n)!}{n!}$.

I am trying to figure out a way to simplify this sum. I am not an expert on special functions, and I would appreciate some references or hints. I have been trying quite hard using a few recurrence relations and other formulas found in the literature.

What I would like to prove is the following:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(k+n)!}x^k(L_n^k(x))^2=e^x+P_{2n-1}(x),
$$
where $P_{2n-1}(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2n-1$ (if $n=0$, we set $P_{-1}=0)$. This is clearly true when $n=0$, and one can easily prove for small values of $n$ ($n=1,2,...$). An alternative way is to differentiate $2n$ times and prove that the resulting sum gives $e^x$, but this approach remains complicated (at least, for me).

I don't know if this is something known, I would appreciate a reference in that case.

Comment: Write one of the $L_n^k(x)$ factors as a sum using your second formula and interchange the order of summation. Then use
$$x^k L_n^k(x) =
 \frac {e^x} {n!} \frac {d^n} {dx^n} (x^{k + n} e^{-x})$$
and interchange summation and differentiation to obtain
$$\sum_{j = 0}^n (-1)^j \binom n j \frac {x^j e^x} {n!}
 \frac {d^n} {dx^n} \left( x^{n - j} - x^{n - j} e^{-x}
  \sum_{l = 0}^{j - 1} \frac {x^l} {l!} \right).$$
$j = 0$ gives $e^x$. $j$ from $1$ to $n$ give polynomials because the derivative of $x^{n - j}$ is zero and the derivative of $e^{-x} x^m$ is $e^{-x}$ times a polynomial.

Comment: Thank you very much, very simple and clear explanation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is [cross-posted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/417888) on MO (and answered there).